# Convert SQL complex query to LINQ or lambda expression

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, lambda

```
SELECT columns FROM TableA
        INNER JOIN TableB ON tablea = tableb
        INNER JOIN tablec ON tablea = tablec
        INNER JOIN tabled ON tablea = tabled
        INNER JOIN tablef ON tablea = tablef 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tableg ON tablea = tableg 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tableh ON tablea = tableh
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tablei ON tablea = tablei 
             AND tablea.column = tablei.column 
             AND tablea.column = tablei.column 
             AND tablea.column <= tablef.column 
             AND tablea.column => tablef.column 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN tablej ON tablea = tablej
             AND tablea.column = tablej.column 
             AND tablea.column = tablej.column 
             AND tablea.column = tablej.column
```

Tables represent the different tables. I've been struggling trying to turn this sql query into lambda expression or linq to eventually pass into my model and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Everything I've tried has been wrong especially trying to figure out the outer join.

Comment: What's the purpose of `tablea.something <= tablef.something` in the join on `tablei`? Is that a mistake?

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell which EF version you have. And show your own first efforts so we see where *specifically* you need help. The best LINQ query is hardly ever a 1:1 reproduction of a SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've got your navigation properties set up properly, this would look something like:

```
from a in context.TableA
select new {
  a,
  a.TableBs,
  a.TableCs,
  a.TableDs,
  a.TableFs,
  TableIs =
    from i in a.TableIs
    where a.something == tablei.something
    ...
    select i,
  TableJs =
    from j in a.TableJs
    where a.something == j.something
    ...
    select j
}
```